# Integration using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

For the following problem from Brown and Churchill's Complex Variables, 8ed., section 84

Show that

$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x= \frac{\pi}{2}(b-a)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive, non-zero constants, by integrating about a suitable indented contour. The contour in question is the upper half of an [annulus](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-k-RyXng1IV0/T1QMEdEpJnI/AAAAAAAABbU/Tk3XK7MzKBw/s800/annulus.png) bisected by the $x$-axis with an outer radius of $R$ and in inner radius of $\delta$, such that the singularity at $x = 0$ is completely avoided by the integration.

I would expect the evaluation to involve the Cauchy-Goursat theorem to show that the integral about the entire region $\mathscr{D}$ which is enclosed by the half-annulus is $0$.

However I'm having difficulty constructing the appropriate complex analogue.

For example I know that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} $ has the complex analogue $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$ and that $\cos(x)$ can be obtained by extracting the real portion of the exponential function i.e. $\cos(x) = \mathrm{Re}(e^{ix})$.

What is the appropriate analogue for this function? Can you show that it would work?

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are no residues to consider.  Rather, consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i a z}-e^{i b z}}{z^2}$$

where $C$ is that indented annulus, where the integral about the outer arc vanishes as the radius of that arc goes to $\infty$, we are left with

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} dx \frac{e^{i a x}-e^{i b x}}{x^2} + \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i a x}-e^{i b x}}{x^2} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{i (a-b) \epsilon e^{i \phi}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}} = 0$$

by Cauchy's theorem (i.e., no poles in $C$).  Taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, we get

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i a x}-e^{i b x}}{x^2} = \pi (b-a)$$

where $PV$ denote the Cauchy principal value.  Taking the real part of both sides and halving the interval, we get the sought result:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\cos{a x}-\cos{b x}}{x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} (b-a)$$

Comment: can you define the value you call $\epsilon$?

Comment: I'm assuming you're letting $x = \epsilon e^{i \phi}$ ? Where $\phi$ is the angle which defines the arc?

Comment: @franklin: actually $z=\epsilon e^{i \phi}$, but yes, you are right.  Note the integration limits, very subtle point about the going clockwise along the arc.

Comment: @franklin: $\epsilon$ is the radius of the arc about which we avoid the pole at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

First write the integral as

> $$ \int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x. $$

So, basically you need to consider the principal value of the integral. That leads to consider the complex integral

> $$ \int_{C}\frac{e^{iaz} -e^{ibz}}{z^2} dz $$

and note that, you have a simple pole at the origin.