# show that $\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac {\cos (ax) -\cos (bx)} {x^2}dx=\pi \frac {b-a} {2}$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac {\cos (ax) -\cos (bx)} {x^2}dx=\pi \frac {b-a} {2}$$ for $a,b\geq 0$

I would like someone solve it using contour integrals, also I would like to see different solutions using different ways to solve it.

Comment: For the contour method: write the integral as $\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ and then deform the contour to run slightly below the real axis. Next express cosines in terms of exponentials. Then (for $a,b>0$) the integrals containing $e^{-iax}$, $e^{-ibx}$ can be closed in the lower half plane and therefore give zero. The integrals containing $e^{iax}$, $e^{ibx}$ can only be closed in the upper half plane and are therefore given by the residues of $e^{iax}/(2x^2)$, $e^{ibx}/(2x^2)$ at $x=0$. These are easy to compute.

Comment: @O.L. thanks for you but can you posted as an answer because Iam beginner In complex integratine

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378587/integration-using-residues/378596#378596).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1**

Integrate once by parts to get
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{b\sin bx-a\sin ax}{x}dx$$
and then use Dirichlet integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**Method 2** (contour integration):

Using parity, write the integral as $\displaystyle\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ and then deform the contour to be the line $C$ slightly below the real axis. Next express cosines in terms of exponentials. Then we obtain
$$I=\frac14\left(\int_C \frac{e^{iax}dx}{x^2}+\int_C \frac{e^{-iax}dx}{x^2}-\int_C \frac{e^{ibx}dx}{x^2}-\int_C \frac{e^{-ibx}dx}{x^2}\right)$$

For $a,b>0$, in the integrals containing $e^{-iax}$, $e^{-ibx}$, the contour can be closed in the lower half plane (by Jordan lemma) and therefore these integrals vanish (as there are no singularities inside).

The integrals containing $e^{iax}$, $e^{ibx}$ can only be closed in the upper half plane and are therefore given by the residues at $x=0$:
$$I=\frac{\pi i}{2}\left(\mathrm{res}_{x=0}\frac{e^{iax}}{x^2}-\mathrm{res}_{x=0}\frac{e^{ibx}}{x^2}\right) =\frac{\pi i}{2}\left(ia-ib\right)=\frac{\pi(b-a)}{2}.$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you used the residues in order to compute the integral?

Comment: I don't understand how you used the residue to caculate the value of the integral

Answer (score 17):

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos ax-\cos bx}{x^2}\,dx &=\int_0^{\infty}\int_a^{b}\frac{\sin tx}{x}\,dt\,dx \\&=\int_a^{b}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin tx}{x}\,dx\,dt\\&=\int_a^b \frac{\pi}{2}\,dt\\&=\frac{(b-a)\pi}{2}\end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 1):

Divide into two parts, and then use integration by parts to get a [Sine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html), and note that $\cos(ax)/x$ tends to $0$ as $x\to \infty$, so that you remain with $\rm{Si}(x)$ which tends to $\pi/2$.