# Is there a novel way to integrate this without using complex numbers?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

I've been reading a post on Quora about [lesser known techniques of integration](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-lesser-known-techniques-of-integration) and I'm just curious if there's also a novel way to integrate this type of integral without resorting to complex analysis.

$$ \int^\infty_0 \frac {\cos (ax)\,dx}{x^2}, a \geq 0  $$

Comment: If you don't want to use complex analysis, you may want to remove that tag since it will draw people who like complex analysis.

Comment: There is no way to integrate this with or without complex analysis, as the integral diverges on the lower bound. See however the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/451455/73025).

Comment: @dustin There might be people though who have answered an integral related to this and might know of some technique that is useful for this type of integral.

Comment: @O.L. This question is very helpful thanks!

Comment: There are analysis and real analysis tags. Why use a tag from a subject you don't want to use is my point.

Comment: The integral in question is divergent as an improper integral at the lower end.

Comment: The integral diverges. Perhaps you meant to write $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}~dx~=~\frac\pi2~|a|$.

Comment: What if I exploit the fact that since $\frac{\cos (ax)}{x^2}$ is an even function, I could just evaluate a different integral instead which is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (ax)dx}{x^2} = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (ax)dx}{x^2} $$

provided of course that the integral on the left exists. I do think that the integral on the left exists though since the indefinite version of this integral is integrable through IBP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given integral is not converging, so I assume you wanted to study:

$$f(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}\,dx$$
that is an even function, hence we can assume $a\geq 0$ WLOG. Integration by parts then gives:
$$ f(a) = a\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx $$
and by replacing $x$ with $\frac{z}{a}$ we get:
$$ f(a)=a\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\,a $$
leading to:

> $$\forall r\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(rx)}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}|r|.$$

Comment: This answers your own question rather than the initial one.

Comment: @O.L.: just because the original question makes no sense without the $1-\ldots$ part.